# ASP.Net core model not found in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm going over some ASP.Net core tutorials. I'm working with models. I've created a Quote model to store a name and some text to a DB but I am getting the error:

> obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor/Views/Home/CreateQuote.g.cshtml.cs(23,92): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Quotes' could not be found.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using DbConnection;
using Session.Models;

namespace Session.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("quote")]
        public IActionResult CreateQuote() {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost("quote/Create")]
        public void Create(Quotes quote) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hi!!!!");
            System.Console.WriteLine("name is: "+quote.name);
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult test(Quotes obj) {
            ViewBag.name = obj.name;
            ViewBag.quote = obj.quote;

            System.Console.WriteLine(obj.name);
            System.Console.WriteLine(obj.quote);
            return View("test");
        }    
    }
}
```

Quotes.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Session.Models
{
    public class Quotes
    {
        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Your Name:")]
        public string name {get;set;}

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Quote:")]
        public string quote{get;set;}
        public DateTime createdAt {get;set;}
    }
}
```

CreateQuote.cshtml

```html
@model Quotes
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <span asp-validation-for="name"></span>
    <label asp-for="name"></label>
    <input asp-for="name"><br>
    <span asp-validation-for="quote"></span>
    <label asp-for="quote"></label>
    <input asp-for="quote"><br>
    <input value="Add Quote" type="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: You can either specify the full name with namespace `@model Session.Models.Quotes` or add  `@using Session.Models`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676269/model-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 3):

**Option 3** - [ViewImports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.1#importing-shared-directives)

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using Session.Models
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Refer to your model as `@model Session.Models.Quotes` in your CreateQuote.cshtml view.

**Option 2**

```
@model Quotes
@using Session.Models
```

Comment: @Bizmark Try adding `@using Session.Models` above the `@model Quotes`

Comment: That didn't work either. Could I have made a mistake with my namespace names? Like in Quotes.cs where I have Session.Models{} for my namespace?

Comment: That should be correct, if the Quotes.cs is located in the Models folder.

Comment: It is. I'm not sure what's going on really. I finished another tutorial with models and I didn't have this issue.

Comment: What is the link to the tutorial?

Comment: It's from a boot camp I went to, behind a paywall. Basically create a model, pass data from a view and save it to a DB.

Comment: What error did it give when you tried the answer to the question? Because I don't see any other problems so this should actually solve it.

Comment: I'm just supposed to get this working. obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor/Views/Home/quotes.g.cshtml.cs(23,87): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Quotes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/michaelmansperger/Desktop/CReview/QuotingDojo/QuotingDojo.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Razor/Views/Home/quotes.g.cshtml.cs(159,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Quotes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/michaelmansperger/Desktop/CReview/QuotingDojo/QuotingDojo.csproj]

Comment: Try rebuilding your project.

Comment: Other two options are running `dotnet restore` or NuGet package restore..

Comment: That's strange. When I build it in VSCode it has no issues. When I run it in the terminal there are build errors.

Comment: Was the project created in VSCode or in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit I had the wrong project open in my terminal. It seems your answer at the beginning solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 - see analysis in [enter link description here](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2018/07/asp-net-mvc-fixing-razor-view-type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-error/) for me this helped as the referenced project was of Windows Application type :-/. 3 hours wasted ... changed it to Class Library.