# The type or namespace 'NModel' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, ml-agent, barracuda

I'm trying to embed a model that I trained in my c# unity script.
By doing something like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using MLAgents;

public class loadImage : MonoBehaviour {

    public NNModel modelSource;

    var model = ModelLoader.Load(modelSource);
```

This was prescribed by [these barracuda docs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/UnitySDK/Assets/ML-Agents/Plugins/Barracuda.Core/Barracuda.md#load-model-into-barracuda) on unity's github. However, i get the error

```
The type or namespace 'NModel' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?
```

Don't really know how I could be adding that  Quite new to c# and Unity programming, so the cause for this error could be rather basic. Am I forgetting something?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676269/model-could-not-be-found

Comment: If you are using visual studio, right click on NModel and add the reference if it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see e.g. in [`BarracudaModelParamLoader`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/UnitySDK/Assets/ML-Agents/Scripts/InferenceBrain/BarracudaModelParamLoader.cs) the only namespace besides the `System` ones is `Barracula` and it uses `NModel` ;)

So `NModel` seems to be part of the `Barracula` namespace.

Simply add

```
using Barracuda;
```

at the top of your script.

Also make sure that the Baracccula `.dll` files are imported and [compatible](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html) with the target platform.

---

In general: I would strongly recommend to use a proper IDE like e.g. VisualStudio for doing your coding. It usually can automatically suggest the required fixes for missing namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am late to the party, just in case someone is still struggling with this problem, simply add:

```
using Unity.Barracuda;
```

instead of

```
using Barracuda;
```

solved my issue